# Mounting the CD rom drive on VirtualBox for a RHEL 6 guest

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to install the VirtualBox Guest Additions on my RHEL 6 guest, but when I choose the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso image from the drop down menu (.iso image for that matter) nothing shows up under `/mnt/` or `/media/cdrom/`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe you're used to working in graphical environments which monitor and mount media for you. If you're not in a Window Manager that does that kind of thing for you, you'll need to manually mount the filesystem, as funny_sailor suggests.

Comment: The problem is that the instructions for installing the VirtualBox Guest Additions don't say anything about manually mounting the file share.  They say "Insert the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso CD file into your Linux guest's virtual CD-ROM drive, exactly the same way as described for a Windows guest" then "Change to the directory where your CD-ROM drive is mounted and execute as root sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run".  Nothing about manually mounting the share.

Answer (score 7):

Have you try:

```
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
```

Comment: That would mount the cdrom directly on '/mnt' which would FUBAR all your other mount points.  You need 'mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom'  where '/mnt/cdrom' is the folder you are mounting to.